# how to get custom environment variable in ansible?

Tags: linux, bash, ansible, environment-variables

Hi I am trying to find out how to get custom environment variable in Ansible.

something that a simple shell command like this:

I created a custom Environment Variable  and assigned a value

`EXPORT SSH_STATUS=TRUE`

who can I access the result from ansible

How can I assign an Ubuntu Environment Variable Value to Ansible Variable

Any clue ?

Comment: As @Ash says work, you can test it with ansible all -m debug -a "msg={{SSH_STATUS}}" --extra-vars "SSH_STATUS=TRUE" -i localhost,

Answer (score 1):

You can define it as variables or you can pass the variables as extra-vars while running the playbook.

```
vars:
 SSH_STATUS=TRUE
```

or

```
--extra-vars "SSH_STATUS=TRUE"
```

To access the variable use `"{{SSH_STATUS}}"`

For environment variable use as below

```
- name: Install cobbler
  command: < some command >    
  environment: "{{SSH_STATUS}}"
```

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please mark as correct answer.

Comment: Thank for your response, I think it work for me, but my exact need is to assign an Ubuntu Environment Variable Value to Ansible Variable

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html).

```
- set_fact:
    SSH_STATUS: TRUE
```

If what you need is the value of `$somevar`,  ***if*** it gets set by `.bashrc` then `register` is your friend.

```
- name: Expose `$somevar`
  shell: echo "$somevar" # must exist
  register: tmpvar

- set_fact:
    SSH_STATUS: "{{ tmpvar.stdout }}"
```

The issue is that you have to make sure the variable is set before you access it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, Actually I need to assign a custom Environment Variable, its value may change from True or False and  read that variable from ansible-playbook, if the custom  environment value is assigned to an ansible variable, we can update the variables as needed without touching the ansible script, thats my final objective

Comment: then you need to elaborate your question.

Comment: elaborated the question . How can I assign a  Ubuntu Environment Variable Value to Ansible Variable

Comment: That isn't exactly elaboration, lol.
Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)... especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Anish Varghese, From what I have understood, I have written the below code which can extract the value of a custom environment variable in ansible playbook, without even updating the ansible.

```
- name: show env value
  debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('env', 'XV') }}"
```

Below is the verification of the above task,

Setting the custom environment variable named "XV",

```
export XV="TRUE"
```

Running the Ansible script,

```
TASK [show env value] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.10.10] => {
    "msg": "TRUE"
}
```

Now, updating the value of the env variable and running the ansible again,

```
export XV="FALSE"

TASK [show env value] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.10.10] => {
    "msg": "FALSE"
}
```

Here is the associated documentation.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/env.html

Answer (score 0):

Ansible has a built in facility for this called `environment` https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html